# errSecUserCanceled not implemented in iOS 8 GM?

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Using `SecItemCopyMatching` to retrieve something from the Keychain in Xcode 6 GM, I get `errSecAuthFailed` after canceling the request to authenticate.

The docs' comments say that `errSecUserCanceled` is when the "User canceled the operation." whileas `errSecAuthFailed` is "The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct". Thus, I was expecting `errSecUserCanceled` in return here.

Have others managed to get a `errSecUserCanceled`, or is the expected behaviour to get `errSecAuthFailed`?

Comment: I just ran into this as well.  AFIK there's no way for the user to "fail" out of Touch-ID other than to hit cancel, so the result code is just errSecAuthFailed.